# Send custom error response in Spring Cloud Gateway when no route matches

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

In Spring Cloud Gateway , I want to send a custom error in case a particular predicate match fails . For eg:-
I have a Path and a header predicate. Something like this -

```
- id: test
  uri: http://localhost:8000/
  predicates:
   - Path=/consignment
   - Header=h,h1
```

So if the path mathces and header doesn't , the request fails with not found error something like by default-

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-08T20:05:42.440+0000",
    "path": "/test",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": null,
    "requestId": "6dd2e799"
}
```

But I want to send a custom response mentioning that the header is not present.
Is there a way to do that?